# Collision equation for two 3d objects

Tags: python

I'm trying a script in maya to see if i can get gravity and that lot working with spherical objects, and currently it works fine (tried making a moon and earth to scale and calibrated the gravity effect to that), but I'd like to try get it a step further and add collisions to make objects bounce off each other, but after looking around for ages yesterday, I found it's hard enough with 2d objects, never mind 3d.
I've managed to write a bit which can detect a collision, where it gets the distance between both objects and compares it against the radius of both objects, which seems to work (needs rewriting though), but I couldn't figure out what to do next. To be honest, I'm not even sure if it's possible to do with something like this without some advanced university knowledge which is why I eventually gave up :P
Just for an idea of how it works, here's the current stage of the main part - objSel[j] is the current selected object, allObjects is everything but the current selected object

```
def moveObjects(originalTime,objSel,objMultiplySize):
    moveAmounts = []
    crashed = False
    for j in range(len(objSel)):

        #get initial values
        originalVelocity = getVelocity(objSel[j],originalTime,objMultiplySize)
        objVolume = getVolume(objSel[j],objMultiplySize)
        allObjects = selectAllOtherObjects(objSel[j], objSel)

        #calculate gravity effect on object
        xDist = 0
        yDist = 0
        zDist = 0
        for i in range (0, len(allObjects) ):
            attraction = calcuateForce(objSel[j],allObjects[i],objMultiplySize)
            distanceFromObj = getDistance(allObjects[i],objSel[j],objMultiplySize)[1]
            xDist += distanceFromObj[0] * attraction / (objVolume*2.15*math.pi)
            yDist += distanceFromObj[1] * attraction / (objVolume*2.15*math.pi)
            zDist += distanceFromObj[2] * attraction / (objVolume*2.15*math.pi)
        gravityEffect = [xDist,yDist,zDist]
        newX = (originalVelocity[0]+gravityEffect[0])/objMultiplySize
        newY = (originalVelocity[1]+gravityEffect[1])/objMultiplySize
        newZ = (originalVelocity[2]+gravityEffect[2])/objMultiplySize
        newVelocity = [newX,newY,newZ]
        moveAmounts.append( newVelocity )



    #-----------this whole bit needs rewriting--------

    py.currentTime( originalTime + 1, edit = True, update = True)
    for j in range(len(moveAmounts)):

        #collision detection
        allObjects = selectAllOtherObjects(objSel[j], objSel)
        originalRadius = getRadius(objSel[j],objMultiplySize)

        for i in range (0, len(allObjects) ):
            objRadius = getRadius(allObjects[i],objMultiplySize)
            objDistance = getDistance(allObjects[i],objSel[j],objMultiplySize)
            if objDistance[0] < objRadius + originalRadius:
                force1 = moveAmounts[j][0]*objMultiplySize * objRadius
                print "Crashed"
                crashed = True

        if crashed != True:

            #move object
            py.move( objSel[j], float(moveAmounts[j][0]), float(moveAmounts[j][1]), float(moveAmounts[j][2]), relative = True )
            py.setKeyframe( objSel[j], attribute='translateX')
            py.setKeyframe( objSel[j], attribute='translateY')
            py.setKeyframe( objSel[j], attribute='translateZ')

        else:

            #dunno what to do here
            for i in range (0, len(allObjects) ):
                mass1 = getVolume(allObjects[i],objMultiplySize)
                velocity1 = getVelocity(allObjects[i],originalTime,objMultiplySize)
                mass2 = getVolume(objSel[j],objMultiplySize)
                velocity2 = getVelocity(objSel[j],originalTime,objMultiplySize)
                m1v1m2v2X = mass1*velocity1[0] + mass2*velocity2[0]
                m1v1m2v2Y = mass1*velocity1[1] + mass2*velocity2[1]
                m1v1m2v2Z = mass1*velocity1[2] + mass2*velocity2[2]
                totalMass = mass1+mass2
```

Answer (score 2):

Referencing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision :

```
for i in range (0, len(allObjects) ):
                mass1 = getVolume(allObjects[i],objMultiplySize)
                velocity1 = getVelocity(allObjects[i],originalTime,objMultiplySize)
                mass2 = getVolume(objSel[j],objMultiplySize)
                velocity2 = getVelocity(objSel[j],originalTime,objMultiplySize)

                v1new = velocity1; //just initialization
                v2new = velocity2; //just initialization
                v1new[0] = (velocity1[0] *( mass1-mass2) + 2*mass2*velocity2[0])/(mass1 + mass2);
                v2new[0] = (velocity2[0] *( mass2-mass1) + 2*mass1*velocity1[0])/(mass1 + mass2);
                v1new[1] = (velocity1[1] *( mass1-mass2) + 2*mass2*velocity2[1])/(mass1 + mass2);
                v2new[1] = (velocity2[1] *( mass2-mass1) + 2*mass1*velocity1[1])/(mass1 + mass2);
                v1new[2] = (velocity1[2] *( mass1-mass2) + 2*mass2*velocity2[2])/(mass1 + mass2);
                v2new[2] = (velocity2[2] *( mass2-mass1) + 2*mass1*velocity1[2])/(mass1 + mass2);
```

Assuming elastic collision, you can do collision calculations for each dimension separately.

Comment: Hey, sorry it took so long to reply, but thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for (i think) :D  I was trying to do the m1*v1+m2*v2 calculation but couldn't figure out how to solve it :p
I'm gonna have to rewrite part of the code first though before I can test it, but it shouldn't be too hard so I'm hoping this will work ;D

Answer (score 1):

While thomas's collision is a good, simple elastic collision equation, at scales of planetary bodies, there is no such thing as an elastic collision.  Or, should I say, the planets themselves don't collide elastically.  Instead of thinking of planets as if they were big bouncy balls, a more accurate analogy is thinking of them as if they were big [droplets of water](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNI-LIVs-to).  While not completely identical, there is a lot of similarity between water drops and planets in the way they interact when they collide.

A good, quick illustration of the math that will produce that kind of result can be seen [here](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/65193).  While that simulation is not specific to celestial bodies, the basic principles behind the 'squishy' collisions still applies.

I also made a version of it for myself with different simulation parameters, complete with tectonic activity and volcanoes, though no universal gravity, (made it lag too much - all I have is a gravity well in the center) so it won't form any large moons.  You can download it to examine/play with [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/su0gitznlhfsewa/jTF96-BiqU), if you want (you can use the mouse to grab chunks of the planet to throw at it; <kbd>g</kbd> turns the gravity well on/off).  Keep in mind that those "comets" orbiting the planet that forms in the center are *huge*.  If the planet was the size of earth, those comets would be around the size of texas at least.

While both of the simulations I linked to were written in java, the same math and physics can be applied in any language.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for the answer, the few times I've used this site I've been surprised by how helpful you guys are on here ;D
This is more of a personal project so the elastic collisions should be all right for now (maybe I'll do something more fancy once I actually get it working), but yeah, the dough thing is pretty cool along with his other projects, and your one is decent as well, you should have left in the option to have universal gravity though :)

I'll come back and look at the code once I get a better understanding of java and that lot, just a bit over my head currently aha

Comment: @Peter I actually tried to implement universal gravity in it (the original dough didn't have it), but for some reason no matter how I did it, it didn't seem to be able to work.  I have no idea why it didn't like it though.  Even probabilistic gravitation (for each point, pick another point at random and tug the first point toward it) made it break.  Couldn't figure out how to get rid of the bounding box at the edge of the screen, either, for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems more like a math problem than a python problem, since the same rationale would work for any language.

Second, if all your objects are spherical, then you doesn't need to actually detect a TRUE COLLISION, but actually just to check if the distance between object centers is smaller than the sum of their radius. You can get quickly this distance (if your space is euclidean) with this function (which I havent seen defined in your code):

```
def get_distance(obj1, obj2):
    # euclidean distance in three dimensions:
    return ( (obj2.x-obj2.x)**2 + (obj2.y-obj2.y)**2 + (obj2.z-obj2.z)**2 ) ** 0.5
```

Now, from what I have understood, you want to BOUNCE the objects. This requires, by definition, that for any moment the object has a VELOCITY property, which is a vector with direction and magnitude. When you update the object position, you must also update its velocity (most probably from its previous position).

Finally, when you bounce you have to consider the object position, its velocity vector, and the normalized vector which points to the center of the other object it is colliding with. Then, you would perform some vector arithmetics to get its new velocity vector.

(UPDATE): if the objects have different masses, and you want a realistic bouncing, then use the Ellastic Collision concepts in Thomas' answer!

So, as further research "directions", I'd suggest:

- Study some basic vector operations, specially dot product and cross product (you'll be glad you did after you "get" it);
- Consider STRONGLY using Numpy, which implements vectors and vector operations in a very very convenient way, so that you won't have to implement a lot of things, and it's very faster than anything you could do by hand. You don't have to learn it all, learn just enough to solve your problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, the way I got the distance is pretty much exactly as you suggested haha, but I also left in the x,y,z values for if they were needed :) The velocity is also calculated more or less in the same way by skipping back a frame and subtracting the values from the current frame, annoyingly I have no idea how to do it without manually updating the frame so 5+ objects tends to take a few seconds for 100 frames :P
But yeah, thanks, I'll check out the product things you suggested soon, gotta stick with python though as it's within maya :)

Comment: @Peter When I talk about Numpy, it's a numeric library to be used IN python, you only have to import it. I have seen a major improvement in speed using Numpy, because when you perform an operation with a large array of points, it's like it processes all the points at once instead of inside a loop (this is called vectorization). For example, if you have a point represented as a 3x1 array, and a set of N points represented as a 3xN array, you could perform an operation with the point and the vector of N points and get another vector with results (say, distances) with a single function call.

Comment: Ahh right sorry, I just looked it up expecting a download but it seems a bit more tricky to set up aha, I'll definitely look into it some more, my knowledge is still a bit basic at the moment though so for now I'm just going to try get it working ;D

What you said about vectorisation though, only kinda half understood that - just say I had 20,000 values stored, part of a different code assigns colours by running through once, getting the high/low values, then runs through again to apply the shaders correctly, would vectorisation work on the first calculation but not the second?

Comment: Vectorization is something a bit more demanding in terms of making it work. You can take a regular python function and "vectorize" it explicitly in Numpy, but that depends on other things, so you most probably should try out Numpy before tuning stuff to that level. Now for Numpy setup, that's way easier than it sounds. On Linux you use the repositories, and on Windows the DL pages are here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.1/